# Meteor: how to load different files based on CLI parameter?

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor (1.2) app I've **separated files for development and production**

e.g.

- client/lib/appVars.config.PROD.js
- client/lib/appVars.config.CONFIG.js

Ideally the "twin" files have the same variables, functions etc. with little differences but (global) variables and functions which are common to debug and production have the **same** name.

Is there a way to call **meteor run** with a **command line parameter DEBUG_MODE = true | false** so that I cad load either one or the other file, depending on the current mode (debug, production)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set different environmental variables and run via CLI with `meteor run --settings settings.json`

Then you just need a development and production (and staging?) settings.json

Example of a settings file:

```
{
  "awsBucket": "my-example-staging",
  "awsAccessKeyId": "AABBCCddEEff12123131",
  "awsSecretKey": "AABBCCddEEff12123131+AABBCCddEEff12123131",
  "public": {
    "awsBucketUrl": "https://my-meteor-example.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "environment": "staging"
  },
  "googleApiKey": "AABBCCddEEff12123131"
}
```

EDIT ADD:

To access your environmental keys, just select

```
Meteor.settings.awsBucket
```

Security Update (thanks Dave Weldon)

See https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Re production vs development, you should have two settings.json files, the standard one for production (.config/settings.json) and a development one (.config/development/config.json) and when you boot outside of production you boot `meteor --settings .config/development/settings.json`

Re client side, note that if you make the key public e.g.

```
{
  "service_id":"...",
  "service_secret":"...",
  "public":{
      "service_name":"..."
  }
}
```

Then only `Meteor.settings.public.service_name` will be accessible on the client

Comment: thank. does this mean I need to have settings.json file which I change depending on the environment? also, where do I put the file?
furthermore, how do I access the fields in settings.json within my meteor app?

Comment: You can put the file in your application's root directory, as shown [here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). For more examples and security considerations, see [this post](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/).

Comment: Updated to answer your questions dragonmnl, hope all ok